# Game Board with Java GUI Swing

Tags: java, swing

I try to do a game like scrabble with Java GUI. The game board should show like [image]. The user enters x-y inputs and the width of the board field is NxN. The user enters the number of colored squares and the colored squares are randomly distributed to the board. User should select squares and give entry on squares. Do you have any advice on which class to use for board?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have advice: Don't start with the GUI first. Build a game model that has all of the Scrabble logic: putting pieces down, add points to scores etc. Do this first, test it, make sure it works, then build a GUI around it.

... But to answer your question: If I was doing this, I'd just use a JPanel and draw the board / handle UI in one place.